# Installing ruby's msgpack under macosx

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, msgpack

I'm trying to install ruby's [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) on MacOSX Mountain Lion (10.8), using [rvm](http://rvm.io) and ruby 2.0-p195.

Here is the error:

```
~ » gem install msgpack                                                                                                                      atma@greyjewel
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing msgpack:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/st.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:562:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1041:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:in `open'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:in `postpone'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/msgpack-0.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/msgpack-0.5.5/ext/msgpack/gem_make.out

~ »
```

---

I tried specifying `ARCHFLAGS=-arch x86_64` using `env` variables but nothing works for now. I'm out of ideas for now.

Best Regards,

Thanks

ps. Here is the `mkfm.log`:

```
"/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0 -I/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT -I/opt/local/include    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib      -lruby.2.0.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: does `/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2` exists?

Comment: After running the cli command you gave me `rvm get head; rvm remove 2.0.0; rvm install 2.0.0 --debug` everything worked fine, thanks :-)